# modify TEdit object properties from function

Tags: function, c++builder, vcl

I have a C++ Builder project (VCL) and have a TEdit button (Edit1) on the form.  I want to be able to set the TEdit button's text property from within a function I'm building.  How do I do that from the function?

```
void __fastcall MyFunction(int myNum )
{
  ShowMessage(String(myNum));
  //Edit1->Text = "Howdy";    // this is the line of code that won't work
  return;
}
```

Below is the button on my form that calls the above function.

```
void __fastcall TTabbedForm::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   MyFunction(55); // just throw integer 55 for a test
}
```

thank you,
russ

Comment: Are you asking about changing the caption on a TEditButton within a TButtonedEdit or the TButtonedEdit control itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyFunction` is not a member of the `TTabbedForm` class, so it does not have direct access to the `Edit1` object.  You will have to either:

1. make `MyFunction` use the Form's global pointer to reach the `Edit1` object (the pointer is declared in the Form's `.hpp` file), provided the Form object is auto-created at runtime, or at least is assigned to the global pointer if you instantiate the Form object manually:

   ```cpp
   void __fastcall MyFunction(int myNum )
   {
       ShowMessage(myNum);
       TabbedForm->Edit1->Text = "Howdy";
   }
   ```
2. make `Button1Click()` pass the `Edit1` object pointer to `MyFunction()`:

   ```cpp
   void __fastcall MyFunction(int myNum, TEdit *TheEdit)
   {
       ShowMessage(myNum);
       TheEdit->Text = "Howdy";
   }

   void __fastcall TTabbedForm::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
   {
       MyFunction(55, Edit1);
   }
   ```
3. make `MyFunction()` be a member of the Form class, then it has direct access to the `Edit1` object (via the implicit `this` pointer):

   ```cpp
   class TTabbedForm : public TForm
   {
   private:
       ... 
       void __fastcall MyFunction(int myNum); // <-- add this
       ...
   };
   ```

   ```cpp
   void __fastcall TTabbedForm::MyFunction(int myNum )
   {
       ShowMessage(myNum);
       /*this->*/Edit1->Text = "Howdy";
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Remy, that couldn't be any more lucid.  Thank you!

Comment: By the way, when I try your solution 3 I get an error "TTabbedForm::MyFunction(int) is not a member of 'TTabbedForm'."   Solutions 1 & 2 work fine.

Comment: @relayman357 for #3, you would have to add `MyFunction` to the `TTabbedForm` class declaration in the `.hpp` header file

Comment: borland builder c++ has .cpp (implementation sheet) and .h (header sheet) both associated to a unit have equal names.